# why css doesnt work when i change my file of wordpress and sql to another computer?

Tags: css

HIII, I've developed a website using "Elementor" and when I copy the file sql and the file wordpress installed on my disk , I moved these files on another computer  and I put it the file and run sql on phpmy admin , the problem is when I run wordpress in my another computer, css doesn't work I mean my design appears in disorder , no positions and so on , can you help me ?

Comment: have you reviewed https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/ ?

Comment: Has the site URL changed after moving?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two parts to WP: the database (stores the posts/pages/settings) and the theme (stores the code that generates the page and styles it). The WP 'engine" uses both to generate the pages of your site.

So, you have to copy the theme files to the new system. The link in the comment to your question tells you how to move a WP site to another server. And you may also need to move the plugins. Quick way: copy the wp-content/themes and wp-content/plugins folder to the new system.

Plugins and themes store their settings/customizations in the database.

Comment: thank you , I've found a plugin "duplicator". It helped me a lot. thanks !